# Calculate the Eigenvalues of the 3 x 3 matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I have been given the homework question to determine the Eigenvalues of the following matrix:

\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1\\ 
1 & 1 & 1\\ 
 1& 1 &1 
\end{bmatrix}

The Eigenvalues I get are: 0, 1, 2

Yet those answers are wrong, since it should be 0 and 3. Any idea how to get the right answers?

Comment: What method have you been taught when it comes to finding eigenvalues? It is clear that $3$ is an eigenvalue, or rather, it is clear that $(1,1,1)$ is an eigenvector. By inspection, it is also no surprise that $0$ is an eigenvalue. Do you see why? Also, it might be useful to see how you obtain the eigenvalues $0$, $1$ and $2$.

Answer (score 5):

**Alternative way** to solve particular this problem because of its special structure.

It is obvious that it has three eigenvalues, call them $\lambda_1, \lambda_2, \lambda_3$. From inspection alone we can see that the matrix has two dependent columns. In other words, the nullity of this matrix is $2$, which implies $0$ is an eigenvalue of this matrix of algebraic multiplicity $2$. Write $\lambda_1 = \lambda_2 = 0$.

Now, we know that $Tr(A)=\lambda_1+\lambda_2+\lambda_3 = 3$. Thus the third eigenvalue $\lambda_3=3$.

Answer (score 2):

Let $A=\begin{pmatrix}1 & 1 & 1\\1 & 1& 1\\1 & 1 & 1\end{pmatrix}$ be the matrix that is given in the exercise.

The eigenvalues of $A$ are $\lambda\in \mathbb C$ such that $\det \left( A-\lambda I \right) = 0$

$$\det\begin{pmatrix}1-\lambda & 1 & 1\\1 & 1-\lambda & 1\\1 & 1 & 1-\lambda\end{pmatrix}=\left(1-\lambda\right)^{3}+2-3\left(1-\lambda\right)=$$ $$=1-3\lambda+3\lambda^{2}-\lambda^{3}+2-3+3\lambda=3\lambda^{2}-\lambda^{3}=\lambda^{2}(3-\lambda)=0$$

So the eigenvalues are $0$ (double) and $3$.